# Adding WHERE clause gives not good result

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My formula looks like that

```
SELECT EMP.*, DIM.GENDER
FROM Table1 as EMP
    JOIN Table2 as DIM 
        ON EMP.M_COD=DIM.M_COD
        AND EMP.ID=DIM.ID
```

It gives me result of 5,597,154. I know that I have 17 entries of certain category = 10 (added `WHERE EMP.CAT_COD = 10`) to the query, however when I try to get rid of IDs with category 10 (that's my criteria)  then I add for instance `WHERE EMP.CAT_COD <> 16` and I get 4,479,430 rows

Why it didn't just remove these 17 rows and how to properly exclude them from the result?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Maybe you should better post your real query, so we may see what's going on. (The real query probably does not have a condition on EMP.ID=DIM.ID for instance, because that doesn't seem to make sense. An EMP (employee?) is something different from a DIM (dimension?), so you would never compare their IDs.)

Comment: Sorry I can't because columns sometimes are so obvious that it discovers client. Well, EMP and DIM is just an alias for the table right? It could be named anything, and ID just have other name (not and ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<>` is not NULL safe and all 16/NULL are removed from final resultset. In order to filter only `16` [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html) should be used:

```
SELECT EMP.*, DIM.GENDER
FROM Table1 as EMP
JOIN Table2 as DIM 
  ON EMP.M_COD=DIM.M_COD
 AND EMP.ID=DIM.ID
WHERE EMP.CAT_COD IS DISTINCT FROM 16;
-- EMP.CAT_COD IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 16 -- NULL safe equality operator
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you use 16 instead of 10? You mentioned the following filter:

```
WHERE EMP.CAT_COD = 10
```

then you said you use this filter:

```
WHERE EMP.CAT_COD <> 16
```

How many rows return when you run the following one? :)

```
SELECT EMP.*, DIM.GENDER
FROM Table1 as EMP
JOIN Table2 as DIM 
  ON EMP.M_COD=DIM.M_COD
 AND EMP.ID=DIM.ID
WHERE EMP.CAT_COD IS DISTINCT FROM 10;
```

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to say 10 :) the original value is 16 through, it doesn't change anything to be honest

WHERE EMP.CAT_COD <> 10 I got 4,479,430

Comment: So you want to exclude EMP.CAT_COD <> 10, and you don't get the expected results even you use IS DISTINCT FROM 10, right? Maybe there is something missing on the simplified query?

Comment: Exactly but its simple join on two fields - same ID and same month code in both tables